# Discount calculcation bug in 1.9.0.1

Tags: coupon, discount, bug, shopping

I upgraded recently from 1.7 to 1.9.0.1 and I am wondering if this is a bug or if I just missed some new configuration, I am not using tax classes btw.

When creating a shopping cart price rule, (e.g. coupon, sub total equals or greater than 100, fixed discount for the whole cart 15), the discount applied on the subtotal diminishes with every additional product added if and only when setting "Stop further rules processing" to "Yes".

I tested this on a vanilla installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug which has been reported and was introduced in 1.9.  There is flawed logic which means when using 'Stop Further Rules Processing' only the first product in the cart has the cart rule applied.  Magento have said *We are checking the issue as there are more reports related to it* but I suspect a fix may be some time coming.

In the mean time we have created a module to fix the issue [here](https://github.com/husseycoding/cartrulefix).

Comment: what did you actually change here? Would be good to see a diff

Comment: Have a look at the [bug report](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/67), I put a short explanation of the change there.

Comment: Was this fixed with 9.2 OR 9.3?