# Discount coupon is not working for minimum subtotal

Tags: coupon, discount

I have created a new "Shopping Cart Price Rule" for discount coupon of 20% off on minimum shopping cart subtotal of Rs. 2000.

For this I set values as under:

#### Rule Information

> - Status: Active
> - Websites: Main Website
> - Customer Group: (selected all groups)
> - Coupon: Specific Coupon
> - Coupon Code: DWL20
> - Uses per Coupon: (tried both  and )
> - Uses per Customer: (tried both  and )
> - From Date: 8/25/14
> - To Date: 8/30/14
> - Priority: (tried both 0 and 1)

See settings image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4d2I.png)

#### Conditions

> - If **ALL**  of these conditions are **TRUE** :
>
>   - **Subtotal**  equals or greater than  **2000**

See settings image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HULED.png)

#### Actions

> - Apply: Percent of product price discount
> - Discount Amount: 20
> - Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To: 10
> - (leaved blank "cart items matching" rules )

See settings image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gFVk.png)

And here is the output of the cart:

> [image]

What can be an issue here?

Comment: Huge timezone difference on your server?

Comment: Also, you could try the Magento default template to see if it's a theme issue.

Comment: @SamuelComan - That is not a case here because in the same coupon rule I changed condition from subtotal to specific SKU which is working.

Comment: I see that you have a custom extension for checkout. Some kind of one step checkout. As @SamuelComan suggests I think you should try it on the default checkout process. Probably the extension is not the problem, but you can at least get it out of the way.

Comment: Have you checked the list of known bugs of 1.9?  Have found this question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24053/discount-calculcation-bug-in-1-9-0-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it myself!

Strangely, I had to put **the current currency sign before amount**. We are using INR (Rs.). So I needed to use "Rs. 2000" instead of "2000". So my condition is changed from (emphasis the difference)

> - If ALL of these conditions are TRUE :
>
>   - Subtotal  equals or greater than  **2000**

to

> - If ALL of these conditions are TRUE :
>
>   - Subtotal  equals or greater than  **Rs. 2000**

After that change, I could apply the coupon successfully even with one step checkout:

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

If you assign RS. before amount that it will not filter condition. what ever amount in your shopping cart when any one apply coupon it will give you discount. I mean if your cart have less then Rs 2000 amount after applying coupon you will get discount.

Answer (score 0):

When you used the currency sign then no filter will be applying on that coupon, Meanwhile condition become the same for all product subtotal.
In your case, your condition becomes the same for the less than or greater than an amount of 2000.

**In my case, I check website base currency which is USD and the default is INR. Consider the Example whenever I am applying the amount 2000 then 
it will calculate Subtotal_amount for coupon = subtotal * current_currency_rate(USD to INR) 
which is 2000*70(consider USD(1) = INR(70)) that's why I have to apply the product which subtotal has 140000 and more than the coupon subtotal amount**.