# Using Subtotal as condition for sales rule is not working in Magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, sales-rule

I have a sales rule that has these conditions. I have to apply a discount if the cart contains at least one product of one of these categories and if the subtotal is more than 25 euro.
The rule works fine if I don't add the subtotal part. As I add that condition, the coupon is not recognized by Magento 2.

[image]

As you can see, I've already tried to use the currency sign in order to make the rule more specific. I've read about this possible solution here ([Discount coupon is not working for minimum subtotal](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33624/discount-coupon-is-not-working-for-minimum-subtotal)) but it's not working. Note that I've already tried with only one of these subtotal conditions: I think that I've tried any combination of them: with different currency signes (€, Euro, EUR) or without, with the currency sign before or after the amount...

Have you ever experienced this issue? If yes, how have you solved it?

Do you know where in vendor folder Magento make the coupon validation related to subtotal? I've looked into `/vendor/magento/module-sales-rule` but I've found almost nothing.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hey, idk if it's the same, but I had problems in rules using subtotal because of taxes, as an example we were giving 11€ discount on order above 49€, it would make sense put the discount and then tell the order had to be above 49 but didn't work, we had to put the order above 38 (49-11) because it was calculating after, and it doesn't make sense because if an order was between 38 and 48 it should be applied since it was above 38, but it didn't, it's a bit confusing, try to add value to order and see if any value above those 25 works, like 25 plus the discount

Answer (score 0):

I'have not found yet a solution for this issue, but I can suggest a workaround to anyone that has the same problem.

Instead of creating a complex condition, where the subtotal one is summed to the categories one, you can use the "Action" section of the cart rule edit form.

For example, I've let only the condition about the subtotal, and I've applied the discount only to items that belongs to specific categories. The rule is expressed in a different way, but the result is the same.